# List of region options

Tags: r, googlevis

I'm trying to figure out how to get a list of all the regions settable through the "regions" argument of options. More specifically my problem is that I'm trying to get as zoomed in as possible to my region of interest (Southern Ontario) but have no idea how

Example below...

```
gvisGeoChart(data[1:100,], 
         locationvar = "LatLong", 
         colorvar = "Speed",
         options = list(region = "CA")) %>%
  plot
```